# install with composer individual files

Tags: php, composer-php, packagist

Is possible install (or download) individual files with composer?

If a package looks like this:

```
- packageName\
    - file_one.php
    - file_two.php
    - file_three.php
    - file_four.php
```

The basic way is to do this:

```
{
    "require": {
        "packageName" : "*"
    }
}
```

But this way will install all files from the package. Is possible install, for example, `file_one.php` and `file_four.php` only?

Exists some alternative?

**UPDATE**

From @SteveEdson comment I write my scenario.

> @SteveEdson The scenario is this: I would like to make a library with a plugin interface. My first thought was have a repository and push the plugins (just single classes/files) here. But now I'm thinking that the best option is make a separate repository for every plugin and save with composer under the same directory (e.g `plugins` directory)

Comment: I'm pretty sure it isn't possible. If you downloaded the files yourself, you could still autoload them [with `autoload: files`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#files) but of course they would be detatched from any upstream updates.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but the problem will be with updates as you say. What about some alternative?

Comment: I don't know -- anything else I can think of would have lots of machinery, such as forking the upstream project and using a script to delete the mold it into what you want, then adding your own repo to composer pointing directly to your fork on github.  Which is crazy.

Comment: If I come up with any ideas I'll post them.

Comment: Is there a reason that you're wanting to do this? If we know the reason, it might be possible to provide a better solution

Comment: @SteveEdson The scenario is this: I would like to make a library with a plugin interface. My first thought was have a repository and push the plugins (just single classes/files) here. But now I'm thinking that the best option is make a separate repository for every plugin and save with composer under the same directory (e.g `plugins` directory)

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot pick individual files from a package. If you want to use multiple plugins that are added on demand, you have to put the files needed for one plugin into one separate package.

If that means that the package only has one file, so be it.